# Sharepoint workflows: Is it possible to conditionally execute steps within a stage?

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, conditional

EXAMPLE:

```
Stage: Get Approval
  if (CurrentItem:Amount) < 100) then
    Get Manager Approval
  else
    Get Manager Approval
    Get Finance Approval
```

Q: Is it possible to make "Get Manager Approval" and "Get Finance Approval" steps, and conditionally call the steps within the same stage?  Or do I absolutely have to make all three separate stages in order to execute them conditionally?

Maybe this is a poor example, but the basic question is:

Q: Is the "stage" the only grouping that allows conditional execution in a Sharepoint workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to collect multiple actions in a step and use this step in the same stage, you can insert a step named "Get Manager Approval" as below:

[image]

If you want to pre-define a step and reuse this step in a stage, it's not possible. we can only set a new stage and use this stage in "Transition this stage" section.

Answer (score 1):

You can only transition to a single stage, but if your example is correct you should be able to solve this by moving the condition to the end of the `Get Manager Approval` stage ?

```
Stage: Manager Approval
  if (CurrentItem:Amount) >= 100) then
    Get Finance Approval
```